# jQuery plugin not overwriting default options

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm putting together a jQuery plugin using the nested namespace pattern, which I've based on the template from [Addy Osmani's book](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#jquerypluginpatterns).

Its a fairly simple gallery plugin and all works well, except when I try to initialise the plugin and overwrite the default options:

```
$(".m-gallery").vPossible_vGallery({
    scrolls: 3,
    scrollSpeed: 200,
    indexable: false,
    autoplay: true,
    rotateSpeed: 6000
});
```

These don't override the defaults. I've not used this pattern before so not sure if it's something I've done or if it's an error with the template. More likely the former...

[Here's a link to it in action...](http://voyced.com/g-test/)

It's not giving any errors, and I don't completely understanding how this works, so it's difficult for me to figure out where to start trying to debug the issue.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Yep! That did the trick. I actually removed myFunctionParam all together as it wasn't being used, and I didn't really understand the purpose of it. Looks like this may be an error in the book! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be some confusion between `myFuntionParam` and `option` arguments. At first glance replacing any instances of the `option` argument with `myFunctionParam` should fix this.